# ArrayList of ArrayList remove collection

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this ArrayList of ArrayList L [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]]
and a simple ArrayList a [3,4]
I have to remove [3,4] from the second element of L to obtain [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,5]]

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {


    ArrayList< ArrayList<Integer> > L = new ArrayList< ArrayList<Integer> >();
    ArrayList<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    l1.add(1);
    l1.add(2);
    l1.add(3);
    l1.add(4);
    l1.add(5);

    L.add(l1);

    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    a.add(3);
    a.add(4);

    for(int i=1; i<2; i++)
    {
        L.add(L.get(i-1));
        if(L.get(i).containsAll(a))
        {  //System.out.println("OK");
            L.get(i).removeAll(a);
        }

    }
    System.out.println(L);



}
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you having a specific problem that you can't find an answer to?

Comment: The question is How can I delete [3,4] from the second element of L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
L.add(L.get(i-1));
```

This makes the second `List` in `L` **exactly the same instance** of `ArrayList<Integer>` as the first. As a result, when you remove the two items `3` and `4` from `L.get(1)`, it appears that you have removed the two items twice. That is why you get the output

```
[[1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 5]]
```

What you actually want is the second `List` in `L` to be a **copy** of the first. To do this make a new `List` instance like this:

```
 L.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(L.get(i-1)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
L.get(1).removeAll(a); // remove all elements of a from the second list of L
```